# Can android use wifi as client to a Sony camera, and also have an active 4G-connection at the same time

Tags: wi-fi, 4g

I have a Sony QX1 camera that acts as a wifi AP. My phone connects to it as a client, and I use the playmemories app to control the camera. 
Is there any way I can have both wifi and 4G active at the same time, remotely connecting via Teamviewer (or similar) over 4G to the phone from a laptop.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try and see what happens? With Stock Android, your device will keep up the mobile connection if the connected wifi doesn't provide internet access (which the camera doesn't). It will show an `!` in the wifi symbol in the status bar.

Comment: Of course I already tried :). Is there a way around the standard behaviour though?

Comment: I don't understand. For my phone, standard behavior is that if connected to a wifi network that doesn't provide internet access (like the camera's wifi), the 4G connection will remain activated. Does your device act differently?

Comment: I have a Sony Xperia Z5. I have wifi and 4G enabled, and when I connect to the Sony QX1 through wifi - I can not get internet access through the 4G connection. Which phone do you have?

Comment: I have access to a rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 Active, and installed the Super Download Lite - a bandwidth booster that allows both 4G and Wifi to be active at the same time - to boost a download. This app has a "Dual Networks" setting to enable both networks that requires root access. 
I had control of the phone via Teamviewer over 4G while I connected to the wifi of the QX1. I instantly lost contact across the 4G and could not reconnect